# Search by field in related/joined table using Laravel query builder

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have two tables: brands and models. The brands table has an ID for each brand and the name. The models table has a model id and a foreign key with each brand id and model name.

[image]

Here is the model table where "cod_marca" is the foreign key and "modelo" is the model name.

[image]

And here I have the branding table, where "cod_marca" is the ID and "marca" is the name.

I want the user to search according to the name of each brand and everything to be listed according to "cod_marca", that is, if the user searches for "Chevrolet", I want the models with id "1" to appear.

Here is my search code:

```
public function buscar(Request $request) {
    $model = $request->get('marca');
    $models = DB::table('marcas')->where('marca', 'like', '%' . $marca . '%')->paginate(5);

    return view('buscar', ['models' => $models]);
}
```

The form code is generic, I just used a `<select>` with the brand name.

Comment: This would be a bit simpler if you have models for each table with a relationship defined between them. Do you?

Comment: The relationship between the model table and the brand table is the column "cod_marca".

Comment: I get that, but do you have [models for each table](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) with [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) linking those models? You can use the query builder (`DB::table(......`) but it would be a lot simpler if you have models configured. Im just wondering if you have them or not

Comment: No, I only have the models table, which has a relationship with the brands table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, Id prefer to create [models for each table](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) with [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) linking those models and use Eloquent to pull the results.

That said, you could do what you want using the query builder's [join method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins) like so:

```
public function buscar(Request $request) {
    $model = $request->get('marca');
    $models = DB::table('models ')
        ->join('marcas', 'models.cod_marca', '=', 'marcas.cod_marca')
        ->select('models.cod_modelo', 'models.cod_marca', 'models.modelo', 'marcas.marca')
        ->where('marcas.marca', 'like', '%' . $marca . '%')
        ->paginate(5);
    return view('buscar', ['models' => $models]);
}
```